# remove \r\n from query result and extract values into a list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, urllib

I send a query like this:

```
    resp = http.urlopen('GET', 'https://api.appfigures.com/v2/values/time/-1/0/?client_key=12346', headers=headers)
    print('Response', str(resp.data))
```

The result I see is something like this

```
Response b'{\r\n  "2022-06-02": {\r\n    "downloads": 1,\r\n    "re_downloads": 34,\r\n    "uninstalls": 0,\r\n    "updates": 0,\r\n    "returns": 0,\r\n    "net_downloads": 1,\r\n    "promos": 0,\r\n    "revenue": "57.05",\r\n    "returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "edu_downloads": 0,\r\n    "gifts": 0,\r\n    "gift_redemptions": 0,\r\n    "edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_revenue": "67.12",\r\n    "gross_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "business_downloads": 0,\r\n    "business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "standard_downloads": 1,\r\n    "standard_revenue": "57.05",\r\n    "gross_standard_revenue": "67.12",\r\n    "app_downloads": 0,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 1,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    "edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "business_downloads": 0,\r\n    "business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "standard_downloads": 0,\r\n    "standard_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_standard_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "app_downloads": 0,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 0,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    "app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "iap_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "iap_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_iap_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_iap_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "date": "2022-06-03"\r\n  }\r\n}'
b'{\r\n  "2022-06-02": {\r\n    "downloads": 1,\r\n    "re_downloads": 34,\r\n    "uninstalls": 0,\r\n    "updates": 0,\r\n    "returns": 0,\r\n    "net_downloads": 1,\r\n    "promos": 0,\r\n    "revenue": "57.05",\r\n    "returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "edu_downloads": 0,\r\n    "gifts": 0,\r\n    "gift_redemptions": 0,\r\n    "edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_revenue": "67.12",\r\n    "gross_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "business_downloads": 0,\r\n    "business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "standard_downloads": 1,\r\n    "standard_revenue": "57.05",\r\n    "gross_standard_revenue": "67.12",\r\n    "app_downloads": 0,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 1,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    "app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "app_downloads": 0,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 0,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    \r\n    "subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "date": "2022-06-03"\r\n  }\r\n}'
```

The world "re_downloads" and "uninstalls" might occur several times in this output. Is it possible to extract ALL values for these two keys and add them to 2 different lists?

For example, a list `re_downloads[]`contains all values occuring in the `resoponse` while another list `uninstalls[]`contains all respective values occurring in the `resoponse`

Edit:

```
Response {'2022-06-01': {'downloads': 110, 're_downloads': 82, 'uninstalls': 17, 'updates': 16, 'returns': 0, 'net_downloads': 110, 'promos': 0, 'revenue': '402.44', 'returns_amount': '0.00', 'edu_downloads': 0, 'gifts': 0, 'gift_redemptions': 0, 'edu_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_revenue': '524.92', 'gross_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_edu_revenue': '0.00', 'business_downloads': 0, 'business_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_business_revenue': '0.00', 'standard_downloads': 110, 'standard_revenue': '402.44', 'gross_standard_revenue': '524.92', 'app_downloads': 103, 'app_returns': 0, 'iap_amount': 7, 'iap_returns': 0, 'subscription_purchases': 0, 'subscription_returns': 0, 'app_revenue': '0.00', 'app_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_app_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_app_returns_amount': '0.00', 'iap_revenue': '402.44', 'iap_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_iap_revenue': '524.92', 'gross_iap_returns_amount': '0.00', 'subscription_revenue': '0.00', 'subscription_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_subscription_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_subscription_returns_amount': '0.00', 'date': '2022-06-01'}, '2022-06-02': {'downloads': 84, 're_downloads': 92, 'uninstalls': 0, 'updates': 8, 'returns': 0, 'net_downloads': 84, 'promos': 0, 'revenue': '285.24', 'returns_amount': '0.00', 'edu_downloads': 0, 'gifts': 0, 'gift_redemptions': 0, 'edu_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_revenue': '386.62', 'gross_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_edu_revenue': '0.00', 'business_downloads': 0, 'business_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_business_revenue': '0.00', 'standard_downloads': 84, 'standard_revenue': '285.24', 'gross_standard_revenue': '386.62', 'app_downloads': 79, 'app_returns': 0, 'iap_amount': 5, 'iap_returns': 0, 'subscription_purchases': 0, 'subscription_returns': 0, 'app_revenue': '0.00', 'app_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_app_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_app_returns_amount': '0.00', 'iap_revenue': '285.24', 'iap_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_iap_revenue': '386.62', 'gross_iap_returns_amount': '0.00', 'subscription_revenue': '0.00', 'subscription_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_subscription_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_subscription_returns_amount': '0.00', 'date': '2022-06-02'}, '2022-06-03': {'downloads': 0, 're_downloads': 4, 'uninstalls': 0, 'updates': 0, 'returns': 0, 'net_downloads': 0, 'promos': 0, 'revenue': '0.00', 'returns_amount': '0.00', 'edu_downloads': 0, 'gifts': 0, 'gift_redemptions': 0, 'edu_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_edu_revenue': '0.00', 'business_downloads': 0, 'business_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_business_revenue': '0.00', 'standard_downloads': 0, 'standard_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_standard_revenue': '0.00', 'app_downloads': 0, 'app_returns': 0, 'iap_amount': 0, 'iap_returns': 0, 'subscription_purchases': 0, 'subscription_returns': 0, 'app_revenue': '0.00', 'app_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_app_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_app_returns_amount': '0.00', 'iap_revenue': '0.00', 'iap_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_iap_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_iap_returns_amount': '0.00', 'subscription_revenue': '0.00', 'subscription_returns_amount': '0.00', 'gross_subscription_revenue': '0.00', 'gross_subscription_returns_amount': '0.00', 'date': '2022-06-03'}}
b'{\r\n  "2022-06-01": {\r\n    "downloads": 110,\r\n    "re_downloads": 82,\r\n    "uninstalls": 17,\r\n    "updates": 16,\r\n    "returns": 0,\r\n    "net_downloads": 110,\r\n    "promos": 0,\r\n    "revenue": "402.44",\r\n    "returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "edu_downloads": 0,\r\n    "gifts": 0,\r\n    "gift_redemptions": 0,\r\n    "edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_revenue": "524.92",\r\n    "gross_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "business_downloads": 0,\r\n    "business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "standard_downloads": 110,\r\n    "standard_revenue": "402.44",\r\n    "gross_standard_revenue": "524.92",\r\n    "app_downloads": 103,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 7,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    "app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "iap_revenue": "402.44",\r\n    "iap_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_iap_revenue": "524.92",\r\n    "gross_iap_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "date": "2022-06-01"\r\n  },\r\n  "2022-06-02": {\r\n    "downloads": 84,\r\n    "re_downloads": 92,\r\n    "uninstalls": 0,\r\n    "updates": 8,\r\n    "returns": 0,\r\n    "net_downloads": 84,\r\n    "promos": 0,\r\n    "revenue": "285.24",\r\n    "returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "edu_downloads": 0,\r\n    "gifts": 0,\r\n    "gift_redemptions": 0,\r\n    "edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_revenue": "386.62",\r\n    "gross_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "business_downloads": 0,\r\n    "business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "standard_downloads": 84,\r\n    "standard_revenue": "285.24",\r\n    "gross_standard_revenue": "386.62",\r\n    "app_downloads": 79,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 5,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    "app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "iap_revenue": "285.24",\r\n    "iap_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_iap_revenue": "386.62",\r\n    "gross_iap_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "date": "2022-06-02"\r\n  },\r\n  "2022-06-03": {\r\n    "downloads": 0,\r\n    "re_downloads": 4,\r\n    "uninstalls": 0,\r\n    "updates": 0,\r\n    "returns": 0,\r\n    "net_downloads": 0,\r\n    "promos": 0,\r\n    "revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "edu_downloads": 0,\r\n    "gifts": 0,\r\n    "gift_redemptions": 0,\r\n    "edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "business_downloads": 0,\r\n    "business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "standard_downloads": 0,\r\n    "standard_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_standard_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "app_downloads": 0,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 0,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    "app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "iap_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "iap_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_iap_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_iap_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "date": "2022-06-03"\r\n  }\r\n}'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's the problem? Whitespace isn't significant in JSON. Have you tried parsing the response with `json.loads` ?

Comment: Always parse JSON with a proper parser rather than attempting string searching or regex

Comment: The string doesn't contain any arrays.

Comment: I dont think I said that there are any arrays. Did I? Instead, I suggested that I want to extract values and PUT them into arrays/lists. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: `re_downloads[]contains all values occuring in the resoponse` there's no array of values in the response. Only two objects: one dictionary inside another. If you want to convert the dictionary contents to different objects and arrays you'll have to explain the logic and post a well-formatted example. In any case the question was about newlines, not reshaping results. I posted an answer to that question

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the response. There are no escape sequences in the response, that's how a binary string shows newlines. Whitespace in JSON isn't significant, so the payload can be parsed directly :

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
resp=http.urlopen('GET', 'https://api.appfigures.com/v2/values/time/-1/0/?client_key=12346')
```

This returns a 404 response with a JSON payload :

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Not Found",
  "error_description": "Not Found",
  "additional": {
    "see": "http://docs.appfigures.com/"
  },
  "reference": ""
}
```

Which looks like this as a binary string:

```
>>> print(resp.data)
b'{\r\n  "status": 404,\r\n  "message": "Not Found",\r\n  "error_description": "Not Found",\r\n  "additional": {\r\n    "see": "http://docs.appfigures.com/"\r\n  },\r\n  "reference": ""\r\n}'
```

This can be parsed with `json.loads`

```
>>> content=json.loads(resp.data)
>>> content
{'status': 404, 'message': 'Not Found', 'error_description': 'Not Found', 'additional': {'see': 'http://docs.appfigures.com/'}, 'reference': ''}
```

`Content` is a dictionary. To retrieve the `additional.see` attribu:

```
>>> content['additional']['see']
'http://docs.appfigures.com/'
```

The string you posted does *NOT* contain any arrays :

```
>>> data=b'{\r\n  "2022-06-02": {\r\n    "downloads": 1,\r\n    "re_downloads": 34,\r\n    "uninstalls": 0,\r\n    "updates": 0,\r\n    "returns": 0,\r\n    "net_downloads": 1,\r\n    "promos": 0,\r\n    "revenue": "57.05",\r\n    "returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "edu_downloads": 0,\r\n    "gifts": 0,\r\n    "gift_redemptions": 0,\r\n    "edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_revenue": "67.12",\r\n    "gross_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "business_downloads": 0,\r\n    "business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "standard_downloads": 1,\r\n    "standard_revenue": "57.05",\r\n    "gross_standard_revenue": "67.12",\r\n    "app_downloads": 0,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 1,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    "edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "business_downloads": 0,\r\n    "business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "standard_downloads": 0,\r\n    "standard_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_standard_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "app_downloads": 0,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 0,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    "app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "iap_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "iap_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_iap_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_iap_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "date": "2022-06-03"\r\n  }\r\n}'
b'{\r\n  "2022-06-02": {\r\n    "downloads": 1,\r\n    "re_downloads": 34,\r\n    "uninstalls": 0,\r\n    "updates": 0,\r\n    "returns": 0,\r\n    "net_downloads": 1,\r\n    "promos": 0,\r\n    "revenue": "57.05",\r\n    "returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "edu_downloads": 0,\r\n    "gifts": 0,\r\n    "gift_redemptions": 0,\r\n    "edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_revenue": "67.12",\r\n    "gross_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_edu_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "business_downloads": 0,\r\n    "business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_business_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "standard_downloads": 1,\r\n    "standard_revenue": "57.05",\r\n    "gross_standard_revenue": "67.12",\r\n    "app_downloads": 0,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 1,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    "app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_app_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "app_downloads": 0,\r\n    "app_returns": 0,\r\n    "iap_amount": 0,\r\n    "iap_returns": 0,\r\n    "subscription_purchases": 0,\r\n    "subscription_returns": 0,\r\n    \r\n    "subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_revenue": "0.00",\r\n    "gross_subscription_returns_amount": "0.00",\r\n    "date": "2022-06-03"\r\n  }\r\n}'
>>> content=json.loads(data)
>>> pprint.pprint(content)
{'2022-06-02': {'app_downloads': 0,
                'app_returns': 0,
                'app_returns_amount': '0.00',
                'app_revenue': '0.00',
                'business_downloads': 0,
                'business_revenue': '0.00',
                'date': '2022-06-03',
                'downloads': 1,
                'edu_downloads': 0,
                'edu_revenue': '0.00',
                'gift_redemptions': 0,
                'gifts': 0,
                'gross_app_returns_amount': '0.00',
                'gross_app_revenue': '0.00',
                'gross_business_revenue': '0.00',
                'gross_edu_revenue': '0.00',
                'gross_iap_returns_amount': '0.00',
                'gross_iap_revenue': '0.00',
                'gross_returns_amount': '0.00',
                'gross_revenue': '0.00',
                'gross_standard_revenue': '0.00',
                'gross_subscription_returns_amount': '0.00',
                'gross_subscription_revenue': '0.00',
                'iap_amount': 0,
                'iap_returns': 0,
                'iap_returns_amount': '0.00',
                'iap_revenue': '0.00',
                'net_downloads': 1,
                'promos': 0,
                're_downloads': 34,
                'returns': 0,
                'returns_amount': '0.00',
                'revenue': '57.05',
                'standard_downloads': 0,
                'standard_revenue': '0.00',
                'subscription_purchases': 0,
                'subscription_returns': 0,
                'subscription_returns_amount': '0.00',
                'subscription_revenue': '0.00',
                'uninstalls': 0,
                'updates': 0}}
```

`re_download` is a numeric field, not an array

```
>>> content['2022-06-02']['re_downloads']
34
```

Comment: 1. You get a 404 response because I intentionally wrote the wrong clientId credentials. 2. I dont think I said that there are any arrays. Did I? Instead, I suggested that I want to extract values and PUT them into arrays/lists. I edited the qs to add a larger example of the response data. For different dates, we get different values. So for example, I wanted to extract all values of re_downloads and put them in a new list

Comment: is it possible to access the values of ```re_downloads```without having to specfiy the date?

Comment: @Jnl: It's a completely normal `dict`; if you don't know what date it will serve, you can just iterate over `content.items()` until one of the values contains `'re_downloads'`, at which point you have a hit (and know the associated date).